# How to print only BeautifulSoup values?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I have built a webscraper with a for-loop. I don't know why, but it returns an url (which is what I want it to return), and then before fetching the next url in the list, it returns a NoneType object. Other than making the script slower, it's not a big deal, if it wasn't because I can't get it to print more than the first url.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from mechanize import Browser
br = Browser()
page = br.open("https://bdkv2.borger.dk/foa/Sider/default.aspx?fk=22&foaid=11541520")
html = page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
link = soup.findAll('a')
kommunelink = link[21:116]
for kommune in kommunelink:
    kommuneside = br.open(kommune['href'])
    html2 = kommuneside.read()
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(html2)
    hjemmesidelink = soup2.find('a', id='_uscAncHomesite')
    print hjemmesidelink['href']
```

This way my output is like this:

```
http://www.albertslund.dk

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\kba\Desktop\kommuneskraber.py", line 14, in <module>
print hjemmesidelink['href']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I've tried messing around with stuff like: If variable == specific class, then print, but that doesn't work. Example:

```
If hjemmesidelink['href'] == <class 'BeautifulSoup.Tag'>:
    print hjemmesidelink['href']

if hjemmesidelink.class == BeautifulSoup.Tag:
    print hjemmesidelink['href']
```

Any idea how it should be? Or maybe even better, any idea where/why my script fetches a 'NoneType' object every second time it iterates through the loop? Thanks a bunch.

Comment: the indentation in the code above is wrong, can you please make sure you have it exactly as it is in your python script?

Comment: you still need to fix the indent on your for loop.

Comment: okay, well, it seems your problem is not the code exactly, but the fact that `hjemmesidelink = soup2.find('a', id='_uscAncHomesite')` finds nothing on the second run of the loop, and therefore trying to access the `'href'` inside it will not work.

Comment: Exactly. I don't know why every second run returns a 'NoneType' object, that I can't print, but I was hoping to find a way, where it only prints, if it actually finds a href. Something like (written in a non-pythonic way, but I hope you get the point): if hjemmesidelink.class == BeautifulSoup.tag is true, then: print hjemmesidelink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not a complete answer, but if you look at the comments this will answer just the part about not producing an error.

at this part of the code:

```
print hjemmesidelink['href']
```

replace with:

```
if hjemmesidelink:
    print hjemmesidelink['href']
```

the `if hjemmesidelink:` checks if `hjemmesidelink` has a value, if it does, then it prints it, if not, it will continue the loop.

my results:

```
>>> 
http://www.albertslund.dk
http://www.alleroed.dk
http://www.assens.dk
http://www.ballerup.dk
http://www.billund.dk
http://www.brk.dk
http://www.brondby.dk
http://www.broenderslev.dk
http://www.dragoer.dk
```

and counting.

Comment: Amazing. It works exactly how I was hoping and yet so simple. I'm still at a loss as to why it finds a NoneType object in between each url it fetches, but this fixes the problem. Thanks a bunch!